# Updating an ios app that uses coredata with a version without

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

We are planning to update an iOS app that currently uses coredata with a complete rebuild that isn't using coredata. If the schema is not present in the update bundle will it crash on existing users devices?

This is hard to test but I'm guessing as the schema is associated with the app it will need to be present even if it isn't going to be used.

Anyone had experience with doing something like this?

Comment: By schema do you mean the xcdatamodel file?

Answer (score 0):

The data model (what I'm assuming you're calling the schema) is only needed in app if you're building a Core Data stack.  It can be removed if you're not building one.

You're app should still be using Core Data for the time being though.  You're going to want to build the Core Data stack to use it to read in the user's existing data for migration.  So if that's the case, don't go deleting it from the app yet.